# What's the sum of elements of this multi-set?

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Let S be a $\mathbf{multi}$ set of integers such that:

$$S = \left \{\min(\mathbf{C}, a + b - 1) | a \in \left [ \mathbf{A} \right ], b \in \left [ \mathbf{B} \right ] \right \}$$

- Note that $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{B}$ and $\mathbf{C}$ are positive integers and we know $\mathbf{A} \leq \mathbf{B} \leq \mathbf{C}$
- Also $\left [ x \right ]$ stands for $\left \{ 1, 2, 3, \cdots , x \right \}$

Can you figure out sum of all S elements using $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{B}$ and $\mathbf{C}$ as parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $C \ge A+B-1$, then the min against $C$ will have no effect and the sum just reduces to $$\sum_{a=1}^A \sum_{b=1}^B (a + b - 1) = BA(A+1)/2 + AB(B+1)/2 - AB = AB(A+B)/2.$$

Let’s assume now that $A \le B \le C < A+B-1$.  Then some of the values $a+b-1$ get replaced by the smaller $C$, so we just need to add up the deficits and subtract this from the previous total $AB(A+B)/2$.

It’s not hard to see that there is one value with maximum deficit $A+B-C-1$, two values with the next highest deficit $A+B-C-2$, etc., down to the minimum possible deficit of $1$ which occurs $A+B-C-1$ times (note that the assumption $A,B\le C$ is essential here, otherwise our count would be too high).  The total deficit is thus simply $f(A+B-C)$, where

$$f(n) =\sum_{k=1}^n k(n-k) = (n^3-n)/6.$$

So the sum of the multi set $S$ is:

$$\tfrac12 AB(A+B) - \tfrac16 ((A+B-C)^3 - (A+B-C)),$$

unless $A+B-C < 0$, in which case you can discard the second term.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, can you explain a bit more why the $A,B\le C$ assumption is essential?

Comment: @CompuPhysics If you count the multiplicities of each value of $r=a+b-1$ you’ll find (assuming $A\le B$) there are $r$ copies of the value $r$ when $r \in [1,A]$; $A$ copies when $r \in [A,B]$; and $A+B-r$ copies when $r\in [B,A+B-1]$.  The assumption $B\le C$ ensures that $C$ lies in the third interval and not in the first two intervals, which would affect the way we count.